# How to implement reCAPTCHA in my Laravel + Vue Project

Tags: vuejs3, recaptcha, laravel-9

I am using Laravel 9 and Vue3. I want to use reCAPTCHA in my Login and Register page. So, I follow the steps below:

1. npm install vue-recaptcha
2. Write the code below

[image]

However, I got a problem as shown below
[image]

Does anyone has any clue? Esp for Laravel + Vue Project